# jQuery keyUp on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a input element that has a keyup event, any number greater than will show a div.

This works if a human types into the textfield.  However, how do I achieve the keyup on page load if I am setting the value via JS?

```
<input id="this_field">
```

JS on page load:

```
$('#this_field').val('4'); //Now I want the keyup to be event to be triggered.
```

I know I can wrap the keyup in a function and call it right after setting the value, however is there a way to trigger the keyup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of [`$(document).Ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)  of jquery .

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#this_field').val('4').trigger('keyup'); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#this_field').val('4').trigger('keyup');
```

or just :

```
$('#this_field').val('4').keyup();
```

[jQuery keyup() function API](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)